# Why does only readline(), and not read() or readlines(), return when reading from a long-lived FIFO?

Tags: python, fifo

OK, I have a FIFO file in Ubuntu.

```
with open(fifo_path) as f:
    while True:
        d = f.read()
        print(repr(d)) ## this is never called
```

This doesn't work, I never get any data, it just blocks indefinitely even when there is data.

```
with open(fifo_path) as f:
    while True:
        d = f.readlines()
        print(repr(d)) ## this is also never called
```

This doesn't work either.

```
with open(fifo_path) as f:
    while True:
        d = f.readline()
        print(repr(d)) ## only this is invoked
```

Only this works. I get the data and it keep reading each line forever.

Any idea why?

Comment: How could a `while True` loop (with no `break`) ever exit?

Comment: Also, dealing with FIFOs, there are details that matter immensely but aren't given here. What is the write side doing? Does it open the file just once, write all its content, and close it? Does it re-open it every time it has more to write? Do you have just one process writing, or is more than one? All of these impact reader implementation. If you provided a [mcve] that included a writer, that would make this question far more concrete and amenable to solution.

Comment: Keep in mind that unless the handle is opened non-blocking, `f.read()` won't return until the writer closes its handle; otherwise, there's always potentially more available to read. That's true not just of named FIFOs but of *all* pipes -- you get the same behavior if you're reading from stdin, for example.

Comment: You probably want to read in chunks by specifying a size argument to `read` -- but as for the blocking, you could consider trying nonblocking mode (e.g. with `fcntl`, though I've had mixed success with that) or asyncio.

Comment: Okay, I hear all of you. The write is a nmon process which writes to the file, I don't know if it opens each time. But, my question is why does readline() work and not the others?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't need this to ever exit.

Comment: @ATOzTOA, because the others are blocking reads -- they try to read "the entire file". Until there *is* an entire file (which only happens after the write end closes), that means they can't ever complete.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Oh, I get it, cool. But, readline also blocks, but until a newline, right? Can you please post it as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read()` and `readlines()` both read the file's *entire contents*, and only return after that content has been read in full. If the write end of your FIFO is never closed, the file's contents are open-ended, so these calls can never return.

`readline()`, by contrast, blocks until it can read *only one line*, and returns as soon as that one line's content is available.